# How to calculate the difference between two timestamp strings in Perl

Tags: perl

I searched through all the possible questions but couldn't find the answer,
so can Perl experts help me on this one?

I have two timestamps like `05/25/2011 05:22:03 PM` and `05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM`. They are stored in *string* form.

```
my $str1 = '05/25/2011 05:22:03';
my $str2 = '05/25/2011 05:34:08';
```

The latter being the time of a job ending and former being the time it started.

How do I find out the difference in dates and time?  The dates are the same in this case but they could differ as well.

Comment: what kind of result do you want?  number of seconds difference?

Comment: is there really a PM?  you don't show it in the example.

Comment: Hi Ysth , I want the difference to be shown like 12 mins and 5 sec.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) module. It has been a core module since the release of version 9.5 of Perl 5, so it shouldn't need installing.

This code demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $str1 = 'Execution started at 05/25/2011 05:22:03 PM';
my $str2 = 'Execution completed at 05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM';

my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime(/(\d.+M)/, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'), $str1, $str2;

my $delta = $times[1] - $times[0];
print $delta->pretty;
```

**output**

```
12 minutes, 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you Borodin for the answer, but it is throwing an error saying Error parsing time at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/Time/Piece.pm line 469.

Comment: @user2457969: Do you get that error with my code as it stands? If you have changed the data then you need to show what changes you have made. As `ysth` asked, is there a `PM` on the end? You say there is in your question but it isn't there in your data.

Comment: @user2457969: If your date/times actually look like `05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM` then you need to use the format `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p` instead.

Comment: well your code works fine now, actually I have these lines 'Execution completed at 05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM' and 'Execution started at 05/25/2011 05:22:03 PM', and using this regex   ($mon1,$date1,$year1,$hr1,$min1,$sec1) = ($firstline =~ m/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);   I am getting only the numeric values and then appending slash (/) and semicolon and storing them into a string to make it a timestamp. But that is mostly causing the issue, can you tell me what should be the regex used to get only the timestamp value from those lines ? I would really appreciate it.  Thanks Borodin.

Comment: so I mean what should be the regex to directly get only 05/25/2011 05:22:03 values from the line  'Execution completed at 05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM'.

Comment: @user2457969: I have amended my answer to correspond to your new information.

Comment: Hi Borodin, still it throws the same error . Seems like the timestamps are not being saved properly. As I am reading it from a file .Still trying to figure it out. But I really appreciate your help and responses. You Rock :)

Comment: @user2457969: I have copied the data you show exactly and it works fine. Are you running my program or have you modified it? You need to show your code and data.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime.pm) and its *subtract_datetime()* method, which returns a [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime/Duration.pm) object.

```
use Date::Parse;
use DateTime;

my $t1 = '05/25/2011 05:22:03';
my $t2 = '05/25/2011 05:34:08';

my $t1DateTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $t1 ) );
my $t2DateTime = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time( $t2 ) );

my $diff = $t2DateTime->subtract_datetime( $t1DateTime );

print "Diff in minutes: " . $diff->in_units('minutes') . "\n";
print "Diff in hours: " . $diff->in_units('hours') . "\n";
print "Diff in months: " . $diff->in_units('months') . "\n";
```