# Perl calculate difference between 2 timestamps

Tags: perl, time

I have 2 variables with the following time stamp and would like to get the difference between them

```
 my $startdate = "2015/01/13 13:57:02.079-05:00";
 my $enddate ="2015/01/13 13:59:02.079-05:00";
```

How can I achieve the time difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two timestamp strings in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483585/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamp-strings-in-perl) Note that the format is slightly different, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Does Time::Piece supports tz offsets? If no, that's a bad answer for this question. For a change, all the information to support DST changes is present, so it should be used!

Comment: @ikegami Excellent point. `Time::Piece` does support tz offsets, but only if there is no delimiter between the hours and the minutes, e.g. `-0500`. Also, it doesn't support fractional seconds so it can't be used for this particular problem. Retracting my close vote.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, For the `:`, easy to remove with s///

Answer (score 1):

Using DateTime, it's simply

```
$edt->subtract_datetime_absolute($sdt)->in_units('nanoseconds') / 1e9
```

All that's left is generating the DateTime objects. For that, DateTime::Format::Strptime is almost perfect.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $sts = "2015/01/13 13:57:02.079-05:00";
my $ets = "2015/01/13 13:59:02.079-05:00";

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%3N%z',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $sdt = $format->parse_datetime( $sts =~ s/:(?=\d\d\z)//r );
my $edt = $format->parse_datetime( $ets =~ s/:(?=\d\d\z)//r );

my $diff = $edt->subtract_datetime_absolute($sdt)->in_units('nanoseconds') / 1e9;
printf("%.3f\n", $diff);  # 120.000
```

If you want the code to also run on Perl versions older than 5.14, replace

```
my $sdt = $format->parse_datetime( $sts =~ s/:(?=\d\d\z)//r );
my $edt = $format->parse_datetime( $ets =~ s/:(?=\d\d\z)//r );
```

with

```
s/:(?=\d\d\z)// for $sts, $ets;

my $sdt = $format->parse_datetime($sts);
my $edt = $format->parse_datetime($ets);
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse your two dates into objects using `strptime()` from [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece). Subtract one Time::Piece object from the other, which will give you a [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) object.

I'm not going to just give you the code as you need to put in a little effort yourself.

Answer (score -2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my @lines = (
"2015/01/13 13:54:01.853-05:00 11860 acuser    *replica_sync_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111",
"2015/01/13 13:59:01.854-05:00 11860 acuser   replica_sync_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111",

"2015/01/13 13:55:01.266-05:00 11861 acuser   *replica_fetch_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111",
"2015/01/13 13:58:01.267-05:00 11861 acuser   replica_fetch_cmd 7f1f9bfff700 10.101.17.111",
);

my %results;

#Group the start and end times together:

for my $line (@lines) {
    my ($date, $time, $id, $user, $cmd) = split " ", $line;  #splits on any sequence of contiguous whitespace

    if ($cmd =~ s/\A [*]//xms) {  #if replaced a '*' at beginning of cmd, then...
        $results{$id} = ["$date $time", $user, $cmd];
    }
    else {
        unshift @{$results{$id}}, "$date $time";  #push the datetime onto the front of the array
    }
}

say Dumper(\%results);

#Subtract the times within each array:

for my $id (keys %results) {
    my $end_str = $results{$id}->[0]; 
    $end_str =~ s/:(\d{2})\z/$1/xms;  #replace ':' in timezone

    my $start_str = $results{$id}->[1];
    $start_str =~ s/:(\d{2})\z/$1/xms;  #replace ':' in timezone

    #"2015/01/13 13:54:01.853-0500" 
    my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern => "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%3N%z",
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $end_dt = $strp->parse_datetime($end_str);
    my $start_dt = $strp->parse_datetime($start_str);
    #say ref($end_dt);  #=>DateTime

    #Do datetime math in the same timezone:
    $end_dt->set_time_zone('UTC');
    $start_dt->set_time_zone('UTC');

    my $dur = $end_dt->subtract_datetime_absolute($start_dt);
    say Dumper($dur);
    say $dur->seconds;  #If you care about nano seconds, you'll have to access 
                        #the nanoseconds in $dur and do some math
}

--output:--
$VAR1 = {
          '11861' => [
                       '2015/01/13 13:58:01.267-05:00',
                       '2015/01/13 13:55:01.266-05:00',
                       'acuser',
                       'replica_fetch_cmd'
                     ],
          '11860' => [
                       '2015/01/13 13:59:01.854-05:00',
                       '2015/01/13 13:54:01.853-05:00',
                       'acuser',
                       'replica_sync_cmd'
                     ]
        };

$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'seconds' => 180,
                 'minutes' => 0,
                 'end_of_month' => 'wrap',
                 'nanoseconds' => 1000000,
                 'days' => 0,
                 'months' => 0
               }, 'DateTime::Duration' );

180
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'seconds' => 300,
                 'minutes' => 0,
                 'end_of_month' => 'wrap',
                 'nanoseconds' => 1000000,
                 'days' => 0,
                 'months' => 0
               }, 'DateTime::Duration' );

300
```

Global matching
...
The modifier //g stands for global matching and allows the matching operator to match within a string as many times as possible. In scalar context, successive invocations against a string will have //g jump from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it goes along.
...
In list context, //g returns a list of matched groupings, or if there are no groupings, a list of matches to the whole regexp.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl

Also see:

DateTime::Format::Strptime
http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime.pm#Math_Methods

DateTime
http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime.pm#Math_Methods

Answer (score -3):

endendAn example, in kinda pseudocode... not going to work as-is, but to give the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;
use DateTime::Format::DateParse;

my $startdate = "2015/01/13 13:57:02.079-05:00";
my $enddate ="2015/01/13 13:59:02.079-05:00";

# PArse into components
my $starttime = DateTime::Format::DateParse->parse_datetime( $startdate );
my $endtime = DateTime::Format::DateParse->parse_datetime( $enddate );

# Convert to epoch time
my $st = timelocal($ssec,$smin,$shours,$sday,$smonth, $syear);
my $et = timelocal($esec,$emin,$ehours,$eday,$emonth, $eyear);

#Do the math
my $diff = $et - $s;

print "Difference is $diff seconds...\n";
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: DateTime::Format::DateParse doesn't support that format, and it doesn't make sense to use Time::Local if you already have DateTime objects.