# perl regex to cut the microseconds in timestamp

Tags: regex, perl

How can I remove/cut everything after dot (.) using regex in a timestamp? I would like to use the output to find time difference int the below code

```
  $_ = '2015/01/13 13:59:21.267-05:00';
  s/\.\d*//;
  print $_, "\n";
```

Current Output:

```
2015/01/13 13:59:21-05:00
```

Desired Output:

```
2015/01/13 13:59:21
```

Code for finding time difference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $str1 = '2015/01/13 13:58:01.267-05:00';
my $str2 = '2015/01/13 13:59:21.267-05:00';

my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime((s/\.\d*//), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), $str1, $str2;
my $delta = $times[1] - $times[0];
print $delta->pretty;
```

Comment: Have you tried `\..*`? This seems like a trivial question.

Comment: I think the `.267` most likely represents fractions of a second rather than microseconds, so in the case of `13:58:01.267`, you probably have 1.267 seconds or 1 second and 267 milliseconds, not 1 second and 267 microseconds.

Comment: Also, you should *really* not be throwing away the timezone information (`-05:00`). Without the timezone, your answer will be inaccurate for some timestamps because of daylight savings. See [ikegami's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27989377/176646) to a previous question you asked for a great example of how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(s/\.\d*//)` returns the number of substitutions which is causing your error:

```
my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime((s/\.\d*//), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), $str1, $str2;
```

Using /r will have the desired effect in perl 5.14+:

```
my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime( s/\..*//r, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), $str1, $str2;
```

Or before perl 5.14:

```
my @times = map { local $_ = $_; s/\..*//; Time::Piece->strptime( $_, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') } $str1, $str2;
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using the output to find time difference. Using `s/\..*//` is throwing me an error to calculate the difference in times.

Comment: That seemed to be his intention, but I've changed the map to use non-destructive substitution. Although this requires 5.14.

Answer (score 5):

The substitution operator does not return the modified string. If you want it to do that, you need to specify the `/r` modifier.

```
map Time::Piece->strptime((s/\.\d*//r, ...), ...
```

---

If you can't require Perl 5.14+, you'll need something more wordy.

```
map { ( my $s = $_ ) =~ s/\.\d*//; Time::Piece->strptime($s, ...) } ...
```

(If you don't make the copy, you end up modifying the variables you passed to `map`, which I consider a very bad practice.)

Might be better off writing a small sub.

```
sub remove_subsecs { ( my $s = $_[0] ) =~ s/\.\d*//; $s }

map Time::Piece->strptime(remove_subsecs($_), ...), ...
```

---

Alternatively, you could use far better DateTime (possibly with the help of DateTime::Format::Strptime). Not only does it support fractional seconds sub seconds, it prevents you from doing many mistakes people commonly do when dealing with dates and times.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for the regular expression to remove everything after the dot, here it is: And to clarify, if you just want everything before the '.' for the string: '2015/01/13 13:59:21.267-05:00';

```
$_=~/\A(.*?)\./is;
```

$1=everything before the dot.